# mysqi stmt error when updating more then three rows?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Im using a mysqli statement to update a total of 15 inputs. I tested with 2 and it worked I tested it with 3 records and it worked so I stated adding more then checked my work and I get this error. When I was just updating the company name and firstname I wasnt getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error     in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the     right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = ?' at line 1' in /homepages/3/d300203244/htdocs/testphp/updatecustomer.php:23 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/3/d300203244/htdocs/testphp/updatecustomer.php(23): mysqli->prepare('UPDATE customer...') #1 {main} thrown in /homepages/3/d300203244/htdocs/testphp/updatecustomer.php on line 23
```

my server is running php5.4 and mysql5.

here is my code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
require ('dbconnect.php');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id= $_POST['id'];
$company= $_POST['company'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$fax = $_POST['fax'];
$email = $_POST['email'];




$stmt = $con->prepare('UPDATE customer SET company = ?,firstname = ?,lastname = ?,phone = ?, fax = ?,email = ?, WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssi', $company, $firstname, $lastname, $phone, $fax, $email, $id);
$stmt->execute();

echo 'Updated data successfully', PHP_EOL;

echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Rows or Columns you mean?

Comment: columns lol sorry bout that

Comment: Just remove the comma after your `?` for email. I didn't feel this was worth putting in an "answer".

Comment: Your error message pointed it out `right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = ?'` the error being right before the word `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma in your query right before `WHERE clause`

```sql
UPDATE ... ,email = ?, WHERE id = ?
                     ^
```

Remove it.

Comment: geez you got it... I got , crazy lol. I will click answer as soon as it lets me